# How do I write trait for a vector correctly?

Tags: c++, templates, containers, type-traits

I'm trying to practice in traits and SFINAE and try to write something like `is_container` for a vector:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct is_container :std::false_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct is_container< std::vector<Ts...> >:std::true_type {};

template < typename  T>
inline constexpr auto is_container_v = is_container<T>::value;
```

And actually such a function:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<is_container_v<T>, int > = 0>
auto foo(T&& first, T&& second) {
    //do smth...
}
```

But such a call does not see the function:

```
std::vector<int> test_vec1(4,0);
std::vector<int> test_vec2(5,3);

foo(test_vec1, test_vec2);
```

I can't see where the error is.I think that the vector should have 2 parameters:

```
template<class T, class Alloc> 
struct is_container<std::vector<T, Alloc>>
```

But shouldn't the variadic template work? or a mistake in another?I will be happy to help

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: @Cameron E0304 :"no instance of overloaded function "foo" matches the argument list"

Comment: and how is `foo` being called? Is `sum` supposed to be `foo` here?

Comment: @Cameron yes,mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`T&&`** is a **universal reference**. In this case it is matched as `T = std::vector<int>&`. Your `is_container_v<T>` currently returns

```
is_container_v<decltype(test_vec1)> // true
is_container_v<std::vector<int>>    // true
is_container_v<std::vector<int>&>   // false
is_container_v<std::vector<int>&&>  // false
```

In order to evaluate to `true` for references you need to **remove the reference at some point** either with `std::remove_reference_t` or even better with `std::decay_t`

```
is_container_v<std::remove_reference_t<std::vector<int>&>>  // true
is_container_v<std::remove_reference_t<std::vector<int>&&>> // true
```

---

The way you have written `is_container` it is actually not that simple to include it.

- You could simply modify your function to handle it

  ```
  template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<is_container_v<std::decay_t<T>>,int>* = nullptr>
  auto foo(T&&, T&&) {
    return;
  }
  ```

  This is quick and simple but in this case `is_container` as well as `is_container_v` still behave somewhat unexpectedly with references. [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YjaRJ4bSKkUzeKM7)
- You could change the `is_container_v` alias to something like

  ```
  template <typename T>
  inline constexpr auto is_container_v = is_container<std::decay_t<T>>::value;
  ```

  This does not fix though the `is_container` struct itself which still behaves in an unexpected manner.
- If you want to included it into the `is_container` struct directly you actually have to rewrite it in one way or the other either by making it a `template template class` or doing something like this:

  ```
  template <typename T1, typename T2 = void>
  struct is_container: std::false_type {};

  template <typename T>
  struct is_container<T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>,
      typename std::vector<typename std::decay_t<T>::value_type, typename std::decay_t<T>::allocator_type> >>
  >: std::true_type {};
  ```

  I added a second template parameter which is defaulted to `void`. This can then be used to enable and disable certain specialisations with SFINAE and `std::enable_if_t`. Instead of making it a `template template class` I extract the value and allocator type (which are the template arguments of an `std::vector`) and then make sure with `std::decay` that the decayed data type `T` is identical to an `std::vector` with element type `T::element_type` and allocator `T::allocator_type`.
  [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cVd9pfFn366jFWek)

Comment: thank you more for your help and explanation!

Comment: @Alpharius I would use `std::decay`. What I am not sure is where t add it. Of course you could add it to the function itself but wouldn't you expect `is_contaner_v` to be true for references to containers as well? I would think about adding it somewhere in `is_container`  already.

Comment: thank you again, I think it's better to add it to the definition itself

Comment: I apologize,but maybe you know why here ```struct is_container< std::remove_reference_t<std::vector<Ts...>> >:std::true_type {}```  returns an error " Ts is not used in or cannot be deduced " ?

Comment: @Alpharius No, it can't be done that like this. You can add it in a simple way to `template <typename  T> inline constexpr auto is_container_v = is_container<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value;` but I can't think of a quick fix to `is_container` directly. I don't have time now but I bookmarked this tab and I will have a look at how to rewrite it in a couple of hours.

Comment: @Alpharius This is the closest to your syntax that I could come up with: [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cVd9pfFn366jFWek). I have written a post about the template deducation for STL containers some while back: [Read it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67170470/9938686). The problem is that it is actually a template itself which takes two template parameters, the value type as well as the allocator. So either you write the specialisation for a `template template` class or you assume it is a class which contains two static class members a `value_type` and `alloc_type`.

Comment: Unreal thank you for your answer, which helped a lot and your time ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `lvalue`s not `rvalue`s, hence to use your implementation as it's use `std::move()` or change

```cpp
auto foo(T&& first, T&& second)
```

to

```cpp
auto foo(T& first, T& second)
```

Comment: isn't that a  universal reference?why doesn't it work

Comment: Yeah, isn't `T&&` actually a forwarding reference in this case? I don't see how this could be the problem.

Comment: For the universal reference `T&&`, when passed `std::vector<int>&`, `T` is deduced as `std::vector<int>&`, resulting in a declared type of `std::vector<int>& &&`, which collapses to the final type `std::vector<int>&`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/13725747/21475